# local variable 'x1' referenced before assignment python secant method

Tags: python

I am trying to do the secant method to find the root of the polynonium (-2*x**6)-(1.5*x**4)+(10*x)+(2) with inithial value 2,3 and I get this error

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return (-2*x**6)-(1.5*x**4)+(10*x)+(2)

def secante(f,x,fp,N=100,emax=0.0001):
    for k in range(N):
        fp=(f(x1)-f(x0))/(x1-x0)
        x=x1-f(x1)/fp
        e=abs((x-x1)/x)
        if e<emax:
            break
            x0=x1
            x1=x
        print(k,x,f(x),e)
secante(f,2,3)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [10], in <cell line: 17>()
     15             x1=x
     16         print(k,x,f(x),e)
---> 17 secante(f,2,3)

Input In [10], in secante(f, x, fp, N, emax)
      7 def secante(f,x,fp,N=100,emax=0.0001):
      8     for k in range(N):
----> 9         fp=(f(x1)-f(x0))/(x1-x0)
     10         x=x1-f(x1)/fp
     11         e=abs((x-x1)/x)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x1' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, so what's your question? I'm inferring you need help with this, but what help do you need exactly? To start, do you understand what the error message is saying? Please read [ask].

Comment: You haven't assigned to `x1` (nor to `x0`)  at that point. (And you never will due to the broken indentation.)

Comment: You also overwrite the values of both `x` and `fp` as the very first thing you do in the first iteration, so you never use the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved
error in def asignation of variable x0,x1 :)

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return (-2*x**6)-(1.5*x**4)+(10*x)+(2)

def secante(f,x0,x1,n=100,emax=1e-10):
    for k in range(n):
        fp=(f(x1)-f(x0))/(x1-x0)
        
        x=x1-f(x1)/fp
        e=abs((x-x1)/x)
        if e<emax:
            break
        x0=x1
        x1=x
        print(k,x,f(x),e)
secante(f,2,3)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You're referenceing x1 before you define it.  You are also referencing x0 before it is defined.  I'm not familiar with the math here anymore so I'm not confident with fixing the code but ultimately you need to declare these variables before the for loop so they exist before they are changed by the for loop, or else they wont be defined for the first iteration of the loop (your error)

Based on this mistake I'm going to assume that you're new to python and explain from that perspective.

I'm not sure what you're going for with that break statement, but it means that your x0=x1 and x1=x will never run. I suspect you need to unindent these lines so they aren't in the if statement?

I'm not familiar with the math here anymore so I'm not confident with fixing the code, but i'll take a crack at it anyway. I'm going to make a couple assumptions about how you want this to work, but I think this correction is at least nearer the mark:

```
def f(x):
    return (-2*x**6)-(1.5*x**4)+(10*x)+(2)

def secante(f,x,fp,N=100,emax=0.0001):
    x0 = x
    for k in range(N):
        x1 = k
        fp=(f(x1)-f(x0))/(x1-x0)
        x=x1-f(x1)/fp
        e=abs((x-x1)/x)
        if e<emax:
            break
        x0=x1
        print(k,x,f(x),e)
secante(f,2,3)
```

I assumed you want to loop from numbers n to N, where x0 is the number you're on and x1 is the next number. Here is my best visualization of my guess for x=2 and N = 100:

```
loop 1:

|x0|x1|
| 2| 3| 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,...100

loop 2:

    |x0|x1|
  2,|3 | 4| 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,...100

loop 3:

      |x0|x1|
  2, 3| 4| 5| 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,...100


etc.
```

I changed range(N) to range(x+1, N) because my approach will actually have x1 be the reference number.

Before initializing the for-loop I added a statement to set x0 to x. Now x0 is defined (which fixes the next error you would have encountered) but isn't very helpful if its the only change.

Next I changed range(N) to range(x+1, N).  This will loop from 3 to 99 in your case (change N to N+1 if you want the final x1 to be 100)

Now you could replace x1 with k, but for readability sake I just set x1 = k.  Now both variables are defined before they are used (you could also change the for loop to "for x1 in range(x+1, N):" for the same effect)

I unindented "x0=x1" so that it would run on every loop except the last one, (rather than ONLY running on the last loop)

Finally I removed "x1=x" which would just set x1 to 2 over and over, which you would have seen that with your print statement if you got past your errors.

This may not be the exact behavior you want but this will at least run, which gives you a shot at correcting it further from your print statement.